# Using a variable in sed to delete a line number by choice of user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

```
 echo 'which line number would you like to delete'
 read lineNum
 sed -i '"$lineNum"d' speciesDetails.txt
```

can someone advise how I use a variable within sed to delete a line number? This is currently what I have but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes. You should just use double quotes. Use curly braces to delimit the variable from the `d` command.

```
sed -i "${lineNum}d" speciesDetails.txt
```